# Embed Puffin/Photon/Skyfire Browser in own app (iOS and Android)

Tags: ios, flash, embed

My goal is to play Flash Movies in my app, which has to run on Android and iOS devices. (i.e. two versions)
I tried using Adobe Air - it works, but is very slow. Now I discovered some Web browsers like Puffin, which can 'play' Flash movies even on iOS-devices. I can call and open them from my app, but now my question: is there a way to embed one of these browsers in my app?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm also wondering how to do this...

Comment: Sorry, we went another way then, we are using HTML5 now instead of Flash Movies.